# Discord Get Guild is not returning objects

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to get a server object by the server ID. I know the server_id is correct, but for some reason, the functions return me none

```
client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = "mytoken"
client.login(TOKEN)

server_id=846557514476945408 #this is my own server id
guild=client.get_guild(server_id)
```

I've checked made sure that my client connection is open.

Not sure if it matters, but I am seeing these warnings

```
<input>:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.connect' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: I only did a quick look but I noticed you used `server_ID` as a variable name but then used `server_id` in the get_guild. Variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: yeah, you are right, i changed it but it is still not returning anything :(

Comment: are you trying to log in through your own account or a bot? On `client.login(token)`

Comment: I am logging in via a bot, and i got the token from the bot, is there a way that i can log in with my account without the bot? i really dont need the bot in this case

Comment: I believe using a user token as a bot is against Discords TOS. https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352
I just see people use `client.run()` more often than `client.login()`

Comment: when I use client.run(TOKEN). i am facing an this error "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232838/discussion-between-lemon-py-and-llu13701).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `server_id` and `guild` variables run before the client is ready so you always receive `none`. It also seems that the code isn't being set up correctly since `client.login()` is a coroutine and is never awaited. Below I removed the `client.login()` and instead used `client.run()` and used the minimal bot example from discord.py to make use of the on_ready event included. [Discord.py -  A Minimal Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot)

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    server_id = 846557514476945408 #this is my own server id
    guild = client.get_guild(server_id)

client.run("TOKEN")
```